# What is after field?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If, a *group* is a set, $G$, together with an operation *addition*, where an operation is a mapping that associates an element of the set to every pair of its elements, satisfying some requirements known as the group axioms.

If, a *field* is a set $F$ together with two operations called *addition* and *multiplication*, where these operations are required to satisfy the field axioms.

What would be the next after *field*? what are the structures in algebra that defined 3 or even more operations?

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/120875/ring-with-three-binary-operations

Comment: There is nothing canonical to come I would say. But one thing that kind of comes afterwards is an algebra.

Comment: @James which algebra, Lie algebra, sigma algebra, or...?

Comment: Well, an additive $2$-category might be a candidate, but that might be overkill.

Comment: @athos https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field

Comment: *Hyperstructures* They have at least 1 hyperoperations and the output of operations would be sets. I guess.

Comment: If you are interested in structures with lots of operations, that's fine.  There is no significance or "progression" with regards to algebraic objects with more and more operations, as the question "what comes *next*?" implies.

Comment: You would have found out at the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_structure#Two_sets_with_operations) examples of structures with even four operations, like Hopf algebras and bialgebras.  Maybe you would even consider logical $\vee$ $\wedge$ and $\neg$ as three operations in boolean algebra.

Answer (score 2):

There are several algebraic structures with $3$ operations, e.g., a *Poisson structure*, or a *post-Lie algebra structure* $(V,[,],\{, \},\cdot)$. The latter has three operations, namely
$[x,y]$ and $\{x,y\}$ are Lie brackets on a given vector space $V$ and $x\cdot y$ is a compatible non-associative algebra structure. This comes from differential geometry, quantum field theory, operad theory and many other areas. For an introduction see our paper
[Affine actions on Lie groups and post-Lie algebra structures](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_41_post_lie.pdf).